Inverter, neutral-earth link and RCD breaker
I'm wiring an inverter in a vehicle and I would like to use a RCD breaker to protect against isolation faults.
The inverter is a Mean Well NTS-1200-224EU. The datasheet and the install manual are both mute as to earthing and use with an RCD.
So far I've established the following:

the inverter chassis lug is internally bonded to the AC output earth.
the inverter output is a non-polarized Schuko EU socket.
with the inverter off (positive DC input disconnected), my multimeter measures >20 MOhm between earth and any of the AC or DC conductors, and a resistance converging exponentially towards about 6 MOhm between DC input ground and either AC output conductor.
with the inverter on, there is 230V between the AC terminals, 115V between DC ground and either AC terminal, and 110V between the earth contact and either AC terminal.

For the RCD to work, I understand I should connect the inverter's chassis lug and the AC earth to the vehicle chassis, and connect neutral to earth at the inverter output, upstream of the RCD.
I assume the equal and constant voltage I'm measuring relative to earth and ground is due to filtering capacitors and the AC output is in fact floating, but I'd like to double check things.
How do I figure out if it is safe to connect one of the outputs to earth? Are there inverter topologies where this would not be safe, or where it would matter which AC output I designate as neutral and connect to earth?

Perhaps you should ask the manufacturer how to use the device? Anyway, why would RCD need ground connection? It is especially used for safety if you don't have a ground connection. The datasheet says DC input vs AC output can withstand 3kVac and output to FG can withstand 1.5kVac so output is floating.

@Justme if there's no path from a faulty device back to the inverter AC neutral through the earth wire then there won't be any fault current to trip the RCD.

Exactly, so why would you need an RCD if there is no fault current that can't flow through you, as there is no path for it to flow. The only place it can flow through you is if you touch both mains outlet wires at the same time, and the RCD can't detect that anyway.

@Justme AFAIK that's less safe because (a) one isn't made aware of the faulty appliance, and (b) when a second fault on the other conductor completes the circuit, the fault current is much greater eg. 10A instead of 30mA as the only thing that can trip is the MCB.

That is correct. When PE and neutral are tied together, either the RCD trips (fault is neutral to PE and RCD detects imbalance between live and neutral), or the MCB trips (fault is live to PE and from PE back to neutral so a short between live and neutral). With N/PE disconnected, having a fault in two devices means either same wires connects to PE in both devices so nothing happens, or different wires connect to PE in both devices so 10A MCB blows anyway. And as you have unpolarized plugs, you could plug the devices in any way so 10A MCB can trip anyway with or without RCD.

@Justme again, AFAIK, a live/PE fault will trip the RCD because the N/PE link is upstream of the RCD. The MCB may trip first, but the RCD saves the day when you have a sustained fault current that's not enough to trip the MCB, but enough to start a fire.

Again, AFAIK, if you use the inverter as floating, without tying either mains output to PE, the current can't leak out of the system, and the RCD offers no benefit. So no small currents leaking that can start a fire, and anyway, if device 1 fault connects phase A to PE, nothing happens until device 2 fault connects phase B to PE. And devices without PE are double-insulated. My point is, if you bond PE to one phase to form a neutral, you need RCB for safety, if you keep PE unbonded and mains output floats, what would the RCB protect from? It all depends if you even can tie PE to one phase.

@Justme I disagree. "Nothing happens until", and then it's worse. This is why I want an RCD and not an IT setup. I would like this space to be about my original question and not about the need for an RCD.

What bad things may happen when PE is not tied to one of the phases and you have no RCD? Also, if the manual lacks install and usage instructions, this is a device usage question, as the manual does not say if PE can be tied to one phase or how to use it with RCD/GFCI. All it says to contact manufacturer if you want the US socket with built-in GFCI.

@Justme I've answered that earlier in the conversation, and I'm asking a specific question about inverter topologies. Thanks for the discussion, I would like to hear other voices now.
